# c# linq to xml , find nested element by it's attribute

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, xelement

I have a nested element xml like below

```
<ExecutionGraph>
  <If uniqKey="1">
    <Do>
      <If uniqKey="6">
        <Do />
        <Else />
      </If>
    </Do>
    <Else>
      <If uniqKey="2">
        <Do />
        <Else>
          <If uniqKey="3">
            <Do />
            <Else />
          </If>
        </Else>
      </If>
    </Else>
  </If>
</ExecutionGraph>
```

Each If element has `uniqKey` attribute. Know I want to find `uniqKey="3"` with **linq** and add some elements in its  tag. it's  element.

It's been hours which I'm searching but I didn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually I have no idea where to start to solve this solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the element, given:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<ExecutionGraph>
  <If uniqKey=""1"">
    <Do>
      <If uniqKey=""6"">
        <Do />
        <Else />
      </If>
    </Do>
    <Else>
      <If uniqKey=""2"">
        <Do />
        <Else>
          <If uniqKey=""3"">
            <Do />
            <Else />
          </If>
        </Else>
      </If>
    </Else>
  </If>
</ExecutionGraph>");
```

then, quite easily:

```
var el = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("uniqKey") == "3")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

(`Descendants()` returns recursively all the elements)

Then to add a new element inside the found element:

```
var newElement = new XElement("Comment");
el.Add(newElement);
```

(clearly you should check that `el != null`!)

Comment: I thought Descendant() function will list only children of the root. Thanks :)

Comment: @Arash `doc.Descendants().ToArray()` and you can see that it returns everything.